# Receiving JSONObject in PHP

Tags: php, android, json

I am sending JSONObject to the server using below code. But I am unable to receive it in server side using PHP . Can anyone please guide me how to receive it.

```
public void sendStatus(JSONObject object) {


        HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);
        String jsonString = object.toString();

        try {

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonString); 
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            httppost.setEntity(se); 

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
}
```

I have already done it using name value pair using following code

```
$datastring = trim($headers['name']);
```

But as in the above code I am only getting the JSONObject but not any tag. So please anyone can help me or provide me any useful link then I will be grateful.

My JSONObject format is as belos=w

```
{
  "user_id": "123456",
  "Objects": [
    {
      "name": "AAA"
    },
    {
      "name": "BBB"
    },
    {
      "name": "CCC"
    },
    {
      "name": "DDD"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you post what are you getting, try using `var_dump()` or `print_r() `PHP functions

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Please check my updated question. I am sending that Json string to the server.

Answer (score 0):

To send the JSON as string from the Android device you can send it as a POST param:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json_string", jsonString)); 
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

or if you want to send it as a header:

```
httppost.addHeader("json_string", jsonString)
```

However, a header has a maximum length so I'd recommend sending it as POST params

In order to work with a `JSON` object in PHP, you must decode it first into a associative array doing the following

```
$jsonAsArray = json_decode($jsonAsString, true)
```

Afterward, you'll be able to access JSON properties like:

```
$jsonAsArray['user_id']                // 123456
$jsonAsArray['Objects'][1]['name']     // BBB
```

Comment: thanks for answering my questions, I am unable to get the jsonString in server side.                        $jsonAsString= trim($headers['???']); what is the key for geting the jsonstring ? In native side i am sending  json string using setEntity , Where I am not using  any key to send it to server

Comment: I understand, and pardon me if I'm wrong, but to send headers, don't you have to use `httppost.addHeader("key", "value")` ?  I believe using `setEntity()` would work if you were sending them as URL Encoded Params

Comment: Sorry, but couldn't get you.Can you send me any links related to this type of problem.